# CSV, получение при помощи PHP данных строки

Tags: php, циклы, csv

Иметься csv файлик с продуктами.
Вот примеры

```
1,"Ведро","Описания ведра",ссылка на картинку
2,"Рачаг 2х40х2.4`","Описание рычага",'Ссылка на картинку'
3,"Доска 4,7","Описание доски","Ссылка на картинку"
4,"Заглушка (Свинцово перечная)","Описание заглушки",'Нечего нету'
5,"Камень,серый'Надёжный'","Описание камня",''
6,Бутылка,'Описание бутылки'
98756543,'Крышка','описание крышки'
```

Задача только в 2вух вещах

1)вытащить id он идёт первым

2)Вытащить имя целиком.

В силу того что имя может быть в кавычках, может не быть, может быть в двойных, может быть в одинарных, может быть с запитыми в имени может быть с точками в имени. Единственное что горант это id который идёт первым, и имя которое идёт вторым.
Мои наработки следующие.
Скажу заранее регулярку лучше не использовать
Мои наработки следующие

```
$haystack = '27,"WWWWWSSSDAD","DHSAJKWIUAFSNCMBSHFJKLZD';
$haystack2 = '16529,"TEST HASTTINGS Crox 4,5 Ft","TEST-test HASTTINGS Crox 4,5';

$pos2 =strrpos($haystack2, '"',6); //Поиск окончания названия
$pos1 = strrpos($haystack2, '"',1);
//$pos =stristr($haystack2,'"');
//echo $pos;
//echo "/n";
//echo gettype($haystack2);

dd("oroginal =>",$haystack2,
    "search element start=>",$pos1,
    "search element end=>",$pos2,
    'при помощи найденого элемента" обрезаем имя =>',substr($haystack2,0,$pos2)
    ); //Тут dump and die
```

Подскажите правильно ли Я иду. название хотя бы вытащить в одну строку надо. описание и прочие конечно тоже хочеться вытащить таким же методом. Но скажем так. Есть в файле csv запись продукта блоки нам известы.
id,name,manual,img,.......
По этим полям строяться продукты и нужно их вытащить

Comment: csv это формат. для формата есть функции для чтения и записи. в вашем случае `fgetcsv/str_getcsv` читает строку и возвращает массив.

Comment: Боюсь это не формат `csv` (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV). Это что-то на него похожее. Соответственно - регулярка и только регулярка спасет автора задачи.